# How to get wget to use the direct URL file name as output file name for a shortened URL

Tags: wget, download, http

I'm trying to download all the books from a URL list in bulk. The list is in a text file in http://ligman.me/W3TuLr. I'm trying to use `wget` on linux for this. All these URLs seem to be created using a URL shortening service. The problem is when I run `wget --server-response --input-file=list.txt`, the files are downloaded ok, but wget uses the shortened URL tag as their name, while I can see in server responses that the `Location` header for the direct file URL contains the real readable book name in it.

How can I get `wget` to write the output file in the readable file name? `wget` version is 1.13.4.

I'm open to any other Linux comnands which can perform the same task.

Comment: HAve you tried using curl instead?

Comment: `curl` acts the same and it does not even support urls list in a file. I had to use `xargs`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`--trust-server-names`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options) option:

> **--trust-server-names**: If this is set to on, on a redirect the last component of the redirection URL will be used as the local file name. By default it is used the last component in the original URL.

Note that in some cases this can be a security risk: you have no way of knowing what the created filename will be until you get it, and conceivably it could overwrite something you want. This [used to be the default behaviour](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2010-07/msg00076.html) until that [issue](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-2252) was discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried the following

```
     $ wget -i downloadaddreslist.txt
```

where downloadaddresslist.txt is the file of the addresses?

Comment: isn't `-i` option the same as `--input-file` which I have used?